# Why does Emacs get my literal Unicode strings wrong?

Tags: python, emacs, unicode

As far as I know, these should be equivalent in a system that uses UTF-8 as the default encoding:

```
pattern1 = 'Wörterbuch Wortformen'.decode('utf8')
pattern2 = u'Wörterbuch Wortformen'
```

However, when I send these lines from an Emacs buffer to the Python process (`M-x python-shell-send-region`) something strange happens.

```
>>> pattern1
u'W\xf6rterbuch Wortformen'
>>> pattern2
u'W\xc3\xb6rterbuch Wortformen'
```

In a Python shell run in a terminal, both lines result in `u'W\xf6rterbuch Wortformen'`.

What is going on here?

My locale is configured to use UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did (might appear helpful later):

1. Created a single-bit encoded file, say `/tmp/test.dat` Opened it in Emacs using `hexl-mode`.
2. Using `hexl-insert-hex-char` command inserted bytes `C3` and `B6`.
3. Opened this file as text (using `text-mode`). Emacs recognized it as file with multibyte encoding and displayed `ö` in place of the previous bytes.

---

Conclusion: you need the encoding system in your buffer which contains the source code to be `utf-8` to send two bytes for `ö`. However, if it is a single-byte encoding, and given that you select the locale that maps the byte `F6` to `ö`, you will get that byte.

PS. Make sure you have `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` comment.

Comment: This seems to be wrong. See this [message](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2013-10/msg00485.html).

Comment: @ErnestA hm... I don't know the internals, but I thought that since you can have source code in different encodings, then the code sent to the python process would also have different encodings, based on what is defined in the file... At least that would be the right thing to do. How else would the interpreter know how to send the text?

Comment: @ErnestA ah, ok, I see Stefan's later comment. So, I thought that Emacs does it already, but it doesn't consider the coding comment at all. Well, then it is indeed a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it was a [bug](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2013-10/msg00488.html) in `python.el`.